# Visual Studio: Project hierarchy vs. Website hierarchy in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, project

Our website has gotten extremely large, and is a management nightmare in Visual Studio, and we need to break it apart into separate projects.  There are currently hundreds of pages in one main project, and we'd like to break it apart by functional areas, each under its own virtual directory under the root site in IIS.  We're picturing something like:

```
http://mainsite/
  http://mainsite/accounts/
  http://mainsite/requests/
  http://mainsite/approvals/
  http://mainsite/applications/
```

and so forth, where each virtual directory maps to its own project:  accounts.csproj, etc.  The root website would handle logon and landing page, but nothing more.

Today, the single project and shared libraries are laid out something like (may look odd because I'm leaving some projects out):

```
Solution 'MainWebsite' (20 projects)
  + Common
      Common.csproj
      CommonThings.cs

  + Packages
      UserPackage.csproj      // Used by requests, approvals, and user mgmt alike
      AccountPackage.csproj   // Also used by more than just the accounts sub-site

  + Website
      MainWebsite.csproj      // Maps to the root in IIS 
        + CSS
            (Common CSS files)
        + ErrorPages
            (Common Error pages)
        + Accounts
            AccountMgmt.aspx
            Web.config
        + Applications
            AppMgmt.aspx
            Web.config
        + Approvals
            Approvals.aspx
            Web.config
        + Requests
            Requests.aspx
            Web.config
        -----------     
        Main.master
        Default.aspx
        Web.config
```

What's a good way to break apart the main project website while still sharing common elements (CSS files, Error pages, etc.)?  Idyllic requirements would include:

- Play nicely with TFS
- Use the built-in Visual Studio Development Server (not `http://localhost/`)
- Allow individual projects to share pages that are currently in a common folder in the main project (the master page is also an issue here, but I've at least seen ways to jump through hoops with this - better solutions welcome)
- Retaining the ability to inherit web.config settings while minimizing them through independent project web.configs
- Have the root website handle logon (currently forms authentication) for all child sites
- All us to deploy individual sites independently (each site can have its own `/bin/` directory, and we don't care if there are duplicate copies of the same DLLs in each - not an issue)

I wouldn't think this is an unreasonable thing to want to do, but neither is sharing master pages :(  Suggestions?